# Why does this replacement rule for imaginary unit not work?

Tags: replacement, complex

I'm trying to replace imaginary unit in an expression with a real unit:

```
E^(-I y) /. I -> 1
```

> `E^(-I y)`

As you can see, in the output I still have `I`. I first thought this might be because of some strange internal representation, but trying `FullForm` at this doesn't reveal why the rule doesn't work:

```
FullForm@Hold[E^(-I y) /. I -> 1]
```

> `Hold[ReplaceAll[Power[E,Times[Times[-1,\[ImaginaryI]],y]],Rule[\[ImaginaryI],1]]]`

For some reason though, the following does work:

```
E^(-I y) /. Complex[a_, b_] -> a + b
```

> `E^-y`

But there's no `Complex` in the `FullForm`! Why can't I replace `I` (or `\[ImaginaryI]`, per the `FullForm` output) with `1`? What is the proper form to examine to see what the replacement rules actually act on?

Comment: What does `E^(-I y) // FullForm` say without `Hold`?

Comment: Yeah, `E^(-I y) // FullForm` returns `Power[E, Times[Complex[0, -1], y]]`, so neither `I` nor `Complex[0,1]` are present in this expression.

Comment: Ah, so `Hold` prevents the transformation which would precede replacement...

Comment: The problem is not just with complex numbers. `Exp[-5 y] /. (5 -> 1)` doesn't work either.  Replacing constants evidently does not work without some extra effort.

Comment: You might also want to check out [this epic MathGroup thread](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/comp.soft-sys.math.mathematica/XPuK5kX6W8E/SN8JCIVJIvEJ)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is with `Hold`, which prevents the transformation which would precede replacement. See e.g. the following simplified test:

```
FullForm@I
FullForm@Hold@I
```

> `Complex[0,1]`
>
> `Hold[\[ImaginaryI]]`

See how in the second case `I` didn't become `Complex[0,1]` while in the first one it did.

So, instead of trying to see `FullForm` of the whole replacement expression under `Hold`, it's better to just see `FullForm` of unheld LHS of the replacement, i.e.

```
FullForm[E^(-I y)]
```

instead of

```
FullForm@Hold[E^(-I y) /. I -> 1]
```

Comment: How to explain this case  `E^(I*y) /. {E -> q, I -> 1, y -> z}`?

Comment: @AlexTrounev `FullForm[E^(I*y)]` → `Power[E,Times[Complex[0,1],y]]`; `FullForm[I]` → `Complex[0,1]`. `Complex[0,1]` gets replaced, other variables are trivial to replace.

Answer (score 0):

Replacement `/.` on version 11.3 works as expected, for example

```
In[]:= E^(I*y) /. {E -> q, I -> 1, y -> z}

Out[]= q^z
```

But does not work in this case (as pointed out Ruslan)

```
In[1]:= E^(-I*y) /. {E -> q, I -> 1, y -> z}


Out[1]= q^(-I z)
```

Comment: It doesn't: the OP has `E^(-I y)` (notice the `-`), so this will fail unless you use `-I -> -1`, which also transforms to `Complex[0,-1] -> -1` before actual replacement takes place.

Comment: It looks like a bug.

Comment: @AlexTrounev No, it is not a bug. It is an artifact of the way complex numbers are represented in Mathematica.

Comment: @HenrikSchumacher This is not a number, it is a symbolic expression.

Comment: `I` is a number, it's just represented as `Complex[0,1]`. Or would you say that `3/4` is also not a number, since it's represented as a symbolic expression `Rational[3,4]` (see output of `FullForm[3/4]`)?

Comment: @Ruslan `E^(-I y)` It is not a number until it is evaluated to a numerical form.

Comment: So what?.. It doesn't have to be a number to contain a `Complex[0,1]` subexpression after the auto-conversion to what you get from `FullForm`.