Replacing complex numbers in expressions
Consider the following expression:
expr = -((I G8 d\[Eta]pr[x, \[Mu]]^2 K0[x] f\[Pi])/Sqrt[2]) + (
  I G8 d\[Pi]0[x, \[Mu]]^2 K0[x] f\[Pi])/Sqrt[2]

I want to perform the following replacement:
expr /. {I -> a}

However, it replaces only one of the two imaginary units:

It sounds like a bug unless I am blind and do not see something obvious. Could you please suggest a workaround?
The same is the case for another trivial expression:
expr = I*f*g - I*F*G


P.S. Mathematica 14.1 on Windows 11.
Edit
Okay, it looks like I have to do the following:
expr /. {Complex[0, 1] -> a, Complex[0, -1] -> -a}

or
expr /. {I -> a, -I -> -a}

It is not a bug, but it looks weird. For what reason -I is qualitatively different from I?

See also https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/29219 ("Pitfalls" Q&A)

And here: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/190791/why-does-this-replacement-rule-for-imaginary-unit-not-work -- One sees the problem and thinks, Gee this must've come up before.... But perhaps three references is enough for now.

Replacement is purely structural, it does not do any calculation. And it is done on the FullForm. Therefore, consider:
expr // FullForm

Note: Complex[0,-1] and Complex[0,1]
Therefore, you must replace both:
expr /. {Complex[0,-1] ->-a, Complex[0,1]->a}

or equivalent:
expr /. {-I ->-a,I->a}


expr = -((I G8 d\[Eta]pr[x, \[Mu]]^2 K0[x] f\[Pi])/
     Sqrt[2]) + (I G8 d\[Pi]0[x, \[Mu]]^2 K0[x] f\[Pi])/Sqrt[2];

expr /. Complex[r_, i_] :> r + i a

